# Golang: Android apps with gomobile crash when connect in UDP

Tags: android, go

I wrote Android apps in go with mobile package, the apps crash after reaching the following code:

```
ServerAddr,_ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp",SERVER_IP_AND_PORT)
LocalAddr, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", ":0")
Conn, err := net.DialUDP("udp", LocalAddr, ServerAddr)
buf := []byte("lalala")
_,err := Conn.Write(buf) //apps crash on this line
```

Where (actual ip is represented by "x"):

```
const SERVER_IP_AND_PORT string = "xxx.xx.xx.xxx:10001"
```

I tested the code on my laptop and they work perfectly fine. I use mobile package only for creating apk files to do the UDP tests.

I tried to use "log" package to trace errors but it doesn't work. I downloaded many logcat apps but none can catch the error logs (or even log.Print("AAA")). I also tried to write logs in files but don't work either, please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815541/golang-gomobile-app-cannot-generate-files).

Anyway, does anyone have any idea about what the problem is, or any ways to locate the bug? (And please avoid using Android Studio which I have a thousand more problems to even install it correctly)

Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file?

Comment: `adb logcat | grep "GoLog"` worked for me to filter out logs printed from the go app. Make sure usb debugging is on.

Comment: Yes I need permissions! thank you for your helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By now we have to manually add permissions to AndroidManifest.xml, gomobile package is not doing that (feature request is filed). Before they implement this feature we have to do it manually.

For more information please refer to this question:

[Golang: Gomobile app cannot generate files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815541/golang-gomobile-app-cannot-generate-files/33819669#33819669)